# Dynamic style for Vue transition

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm working on a VueJS sidebar component. It should allow the parent to specify a width and render a toggle that slides the sidebar in and out. Something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="sidebarContainer">
    <transition
        name="slide"
    >
      <div v-if="isOpen" class="sidebar" :style="{ width }">
        <slot/>
      </div>
    </transition>
    <div class="toggle" @click="isOpen = !isOpen">&lt;&gt;</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  props: {
    'width': {
      default: '20em',
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: true,
    };
  },
};
```

```css
<style scoped>
.slide-enter-active, .slide-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.slide-enter, .slide-leave-to {
  margin-left: -20em;
}
</style>
```

Working [codepen](https://codepen.io/djbcp/pen/MxNvaO?editors=0110). It works exactly how I want, *except* that the width for the transition (as specified in `.slide-enter, .slide-leave-to` style) is hard coded and not responsive to the component `width` property. If you set `width=30em` then the transition is jumpy.

I suspect that I might need to use [transition hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks), but I can't seem to get that to work. I tried this:

```js
beforeEnter(el) {
  el.style = {
    transition: 'all 0.6s',
    marginLeft: '-20em',
  };
},
enter(el, done) {
  el.style.marginLeft = '0';
  done();
},
beforeLeave(el) {
  el.style = {
    transition: 'all 0.6s',
    marginLeft: '0',
  };
},
leave(el, done) {
  el.style.marginLeft = '-20em';
  done();
},
```

See [modified codepen](https://codepen.io/djbcp/pen/qvexjN?editors=0110). You can see that the sidebar still moves, but instantaneously with no animation. I thought that maybe wrapping the `done` callback in `setTimeout` to allow the transition to complete would help, but it does not.

I know I could use a library like Velocity or I could manually code the animation, but it seems like there should be a way to just let CSS take care of it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First,** your way to set style just not work

```
el.style = {
   transition: 'all 0.6s',
   marginLeft: '-20em',
};
```

I just move `transition: 'all 0.6s'` to css and set style like this

```
el.style.marginLeft = '-20em';
```

**Second,** `enter` event is called very soon after `beforeEnter` event so the browser cannot detect change between two states. So I wrap `enter` event into `setTimeout` to make a trick to trigger the transition.
**Third,** `done` callback is not necessary in this case. It's only required in pure js transition. We are using mixed CSS and JS

```js
Vue.component('app', {
  template: `<div class="app">
    <sidebar>sidebar content</sidebar>
    <div class="main">Hello, VueJS!</div>
  </div>`
});

Vue.component('sidebar', {
  template: `  <div class="sidebarContainer">
    <transition
        name="slide"
        @before-enter="beforeEnter"
        @enter="enter"
        @leave="leave"
    >
      <div v-if="isOpen" class="sidebar" :style="{ width }">
        <slot/>
      </div>
    </transition>
    <div class="toggle" @click="isOpen = !isOpen">&lt;&gt;</div>
  </div>`,
  props: {
    'width': {
      default: '20em',
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    beforeEnter(el) {
      el.style.marginLeft = '-20em';
    },
    enter(el, done) {
      // Wait a tick here, so browser can detect style change and tigger transition
      setTimeout(() => {
        el.style.marginLeft = '0';
      }, 0)
    },
    leave(el, done) {
      el.style.marginLeft = '-20em';
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<app/>'
});
```

```css
html,
body,
.app {
  height: 100%;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: red;
}

.sidebarContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: blue;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}

.toggle {
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I found that I had to set the timeout to 1 instead of 0, but then it worked perfectly. Thanks for all your help!